# Wordprees OceanWP Problem. jquery ” $ is not a function”

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I am using ocean wp theme. When I build a custom Html block in elementor and publish it, it seems that jquery is not defined. neither defining a jquery CDN in the html elemetonr block works nor in custom js panel. it always errors $ is not a function. how can I fix it?
it is interesting that in the Html block when I am in the panel and writing the code I do not get such an error and the code works properly. but when I publish it, it will error and js part will not work. HELP PLEASE:)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that The '$' symbol is used by different libraries for different functions. by default, it's disabled in order to avoid conflict with other scripts that use $. but in your case, there is 2 solutions 
1 use "jQuery" instead of $ 
2 there seems to be no other function using '$'. You can fix the issue by adding the following snippet:

```
 $ = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  //Add your javascript here
```

thanks for support of word press

Add the jQuery noConflict function just above your javascript and it should work.